# Connecting LAN of first router to WAN of second router not working

Tags: networking, router, lan, home-networking, wan

So I have 2 routers 
 
(first provided by the ISP: **Speedport smart 3**) 
(second is my personal:  **Tp-link Archer AX23 AX1800**)

And what I want is to connect my second router to the router provided by my ISP. 
And I want it connected LAN from my first router to the WAN of my second router. 
 
 I am aware that this is going to create 2 networks (and double NAT) and that is fine because the first router would be used by everybody in the house and the second router would be used by my homelab which should be separated from everything else.

### How everything is configured right now:

My first router: 
IP:             **192.168.1.1** 
Subnet mask:    **255.255.255.0** 
DHCP:           **Enabled** 
NAT:            **Enabled** *(cannot turn it off actually)* 
LAN ip range:  **192.168.1.41** - **192.168.1.253** *(this is not a typo I was messing with this that is why the weird ip range but there is nothing special behind this just didn't place it back)*

- also on the first router I've set the **192.168.1.110** ip as static in DHCP and I've set it to the MAC address of the second router

Second router: 
IP:             **192.168.2.2** 
Subnet mask:    **255.255.255.0** 
DHCP:           **Enabled** 
NAT:            **Enabled** 
LAN ip range:  **192.168.2.100** - **192.168.2.249**

Now for the second router for the internet options I've selected the static IP and as you can notice it's the same static IP that I've assigned on the first router

[image: Second router settings]

I've tried dynamic IP as well nothing really changed.

### Now what about the devices connected?

**Mac mini is connected to the first router.** 
As you can see the default gateway is good and the ip is in correct range. The internet is working fine.

[image: mac connection info]

**Windows laptop connected to the second router (tried both Wifi and Ethernet)** *Also if the laptop connects to the first router it works, it has internet just fine*

As you can see it's connected to get default gateway of the second router which is good the ip it got is on the correct subnet which is good. But there is no internet

[image: windows connection info]

Now the picture below is the second router and you can see the internet light is red. So even the router recognises that there is no internet. And yes I've plugged the cables correctly, they are easy to spot on these routers with colours, big text etc. And the ethernet cable is fine (I have equipment to test the cable) and when I tried LAN to LAN setup it worked just fine.

[image: the router]

If anyone has any ideas that I could try to troubleshoot or you just straight up knows what is wrong I would greatly appreciate the help

Comment: Connect LAN to LAN not LAN to WAN and ensure there is just ONE DHCP server. You likely have more than one DHCP server.  Simplify what you are trying to do.

Comment: since you don't need systems on router1 to access systems on router 2, your general idea and architecture are fine. The red light on the router is likely to be about the cable than whether or not the software detects the internet. that would be unusual. if you hold both ends of the cable connecting the routers up next to eachother with the spring clips both pointing the same way, is the orange cable on the same side on both of them (a straight-through cable)? https://www.eeweb.com/wp-content/uploads/articles-quizzes-connector-1426122245.jpg . can you ping router1 LAN from behind router2?

Comment: What OP's doing should work as double NAT, and there's often reasons to do so @John. I run a setup similar to that cause my ISP only does ONR and some of my homelab stuff has overheated consumer routers in the past :D

Comment: Few tests would  be nice - connected to the second router - try pinging then tracerouting 8.8.8.8 and also google.com, to verify if the issue is with connectivity as a whole or DNS

Comment: Do you want to make router 2 expose the same network the router 1 is creating? Or you are creating a second network on purpose for whatever reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For those having this kind of issue and are just looking for solution it's to start quick setup on tplink router and the router will resolve the ip problem that was the issue in the question.**
 
The rest of the answer is how I got to the solution and maybe it can help in case the quick setup does not work and you need inspiration what else to try.

So I have good news and bad news.

The good news I've solved the issue and it's working now. 
The bad news I'm not sure why it works now and it didn't before. *(but the fix is interesting)*

So after reading the comments I've tried looking at the cables like @Frank Thomas said and the cable was a straight-through cable. And my first thought was that this is not the issue because these are new routers so they should be able to resolve (switch if needed). But I didn't want to take the risk so I've made a crossover cable and tried with it but no difference.

Then I tried trace routing a ping like @Jouerneyman Geek suggested and what ping gave was a request timeout when trying to ping 8.8.8.8 and when trying to ping 192.168.1.1 (ip of the first router).

So I tried to remove the static ip for the second router from the first router DHCP settings. Basically just allow the first router to give the second router any ip and this is when something interesting happened. The first router didn't want to assign an ip to the second router. It would show the router when I connect them and it shows the second router MAC address and it's correct but the IP column is just blank. So then on to the second router changed the static IP on the Internet settings from the 192.168.1.110 that I assigned when asking the question to dynamic option. 

And still no change *(just to mention I've done reboots for the first router and the second router many times just to make sure, because I've read that some settings just don't apply without a reboot. So to make sure it's not that issue I've reboot after any significant change)*

And at this point I didn't even have an idea what to try else so I've look on tp-link forums and I've found a thread where the guys were connecting a tp-link router to some media hub and they did it over the wan port on the tp-link router. And it didn't work so one of the answers suggested to go over the quick setup again. *(couldn't find the link to the thread again)* 
 
Basically the quick setup is a setup that is launched the first time you turn on your router or factory reset your router but you can start this quick start from the setting at any time.

And with quick setup I clicked the AUTO DETECT button. Which is not an option when selecting the connection type in settings, all the connection types are in both drop downs but the quick start page has an auto detect button which the settings page does not have. This auto detect button selected the dynamic IP and after next, next, finish and it just started working.

I've checked the settings that it configured and it basically done everything I've done just I've used 192.168.2.x for the LAN and it is using 192.168.0.x. Nothing aside from this is different that I can see... just weird. And I didn't even have to reboot the router it just worked the second the quick setup finished, the light turned green and it was able to connect to internet.

So for anyone Googling this because your having the same issue basically the solution is to use the tplink quick setup so the router handles everything. It might work for other routers as well if they have quick setup. 
Thanks for comments and help

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).